# Using mmap with popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, mmap, zcat

I need to read in and process a bunch of ~40mb gzipped text files, and I need it done fast and with minimal i/o overhead (as the volumes are used by others as well). The fastest way I've found thus for this task looks like this:

```
def gziplines(fname): 
    f = Popen(['zcat', fname], stdout=PIPE)
    for line in f.stdout:
        yield line
```

and then:

```
for line in gziplines(filename)
    dostuff(line)
```

but what I would like to do (*IF* this is faster?) is something like this:

```
def gzipmmap(fname): 
    f = Popen(['zcat', fname], stdout=PIPE)
    m = mmap.mmap(f.stdout.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    return m
```

sadly, when I try this, I get this error:

```
>>> m = mmap.mmap(f.stdout.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
mmap.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

even though, when I try:

```
>>> f.stdout.fileno()
4
```

So, I think I have a basic misunderstanding of what is going on here. :(

The two questions are:

1) Would this mmap be a faster method at putting the whole file into memory for processing?

2) How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much... everyone here has been incredibly helpful already!
~Nik

Comment: Your generator solution is clearer than using mmap, anyway. Have you tried using Python's standard gzip library, rather than calling an external program? http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `mmap(2)` man page:

> ```
>    ENODEV The  underlying  file system of the specified file does not sup-
>           port memory mapping.
> ```

You cannot mmap streams, only real files or anonymous swap space. You will need to read from the stream into memory yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Returning to this over a year later... having a much better understanding of mmap and just about everything else!

Answer (score 1):

Pipes aren't mmapable.

```
case MAP_PRIVATE:
      ...
if (!file->f_op || !file->f_op->mmap)
        return -ENODEV;
```

and pipe's file operations does not contain `mmap` hook.